# Aligning, centering, positioning elements in Boostrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm learning Bootstrap, Javascript, React, etc. in order to make responsive web pages. I have difficulties the positioning the elements on my project. There are lots of properties align, vertical centering, position (absolute, relative etc.), flex, align-content item etc. I'm confused with them when I put on an element somewhere. 
About positioning, I want to watch or read some exercises in order to know exactly this stuff. Do you have any recommendations about that? Which keyword should I use to search this subject on the internet? 
For example, now I'm practicing examples of Bootstrap on the bootstrap official page. But every time they use another properties for position an element. Therefore, I'm getting confused.

Comment: It'd be useful to provide more focus for this question, such as a specific example, or to at least enumerate the specific positioning attributes you're confused about. As is, between CSS and Bootstrap, there's a wide variety of answers that could be given, which may or may not actually help you without a concrete example.

Comment: CSS Tricks does a good job in some of their guides with visuals and explanations. For example: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn bootstrap would be the documentation in my opinion. If you want a lesson though and you are willing to pay, I would recommend Angela Yu's full stack web development course on Udemy which gave me a great understanding of how to use bootstrap effectively. Udemy courses are usually cheap and usually have big sales. This tutorial on youtube is pretty solid as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmPmwdshCMw . My advice with positioning is get comfortable using the 'col' and 'row' classes and the variations of those.